# Convert legacy join to SQL92

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I convert the following query to SQL 92 with LEFT OUTER and RIGHT OUTER Join?

```
SELECT in.ItemNo, ip.ItemPrice, c.CustomerName
FROM inventories in, InventoryPrice ip, Customer c
WHERE in.itemno * = ip.itemno
AND ip.CustId = * c.CustId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
     in.ItemNo
    ,ip.ItemPrice
    ,c.CustomerName
from       inventories    as in
left  join InventoryPrice as ip on ip.itemno = in.itemno
right join Customer       as  c on ip.CustId = c.CustId
```

Note that the reversed syntax on the legacy join code results in a confused left- then right-join. This actually seems to be an error in the legacy code, but one cannot be sure without knowing the data structures precisely..

Comment: you are right, I had tried this one and does not give me the result as the legacy one. Introducing CROSS JOIN does the job but was wondering whether I could avoid that. But if CROSS JOIN is what legacy join is doing anyway, it is fine by me.

Comment: @Aryan: It is a matter of whether the associativity of the legacy syntax is left- or right-associative for the second join; I couldn't find a good reference on the old syntax. Try making both joins LEFT OUTER and see if that agrees with the legacy syntax - that should perform a CROSS JOIN between `Inventories` and `Customer`, which is then LEFT OUTER joined to `InventoryPrice`

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT in.ItemNo, ip.ItemPrice, c.CustomerName
FROM inventories AS in
LEFT JOIN InventoryPrice AS ip ON ip.itemno = in.itemno
LEFT JOIN Customer AS c ON ip.CustId = c.CustId
```

Comment: The last `left join` should be a `right join`. This answer is wrong.